# "Ember Simple Auth" invalidateSession from component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

Trying to execute this code within a component's template

```
// components/my-component.js
{{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
  <a {{action 'invalidateSession'}}>Sign out</a>
{{else}}
  {{#link-to 'signin'}}Sign in{{/link-to}}
{{/if}}
```

However, when clicking "Sign out" button I get this error

```
Error: <...@component:my-component::ember381> had no action handler for: invalidateSession
```

How do I make "invalidateSession" available from a component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just implement your own `invalidateSession` action:

```
actions: {
  invalidateSession: function() {
    this.get('session').invalidate();
  }
}
```

or simply forward the action from the component to the route:

```
{{my-component invalidateSession='invalidateSession'}}
```

Comment: Your first solution works great, however I can't get the second one to work. I create a new component using `{{my-component invalidateSession='invalidateSession'}}`; then, what should I use inside my component's template? `{{action 'invalidateSession'}}` or `{{action invalidateSession}}` (both of these don't seem to work)?

Comment: Yeah, there's a bit more to it actually. You need to define the `invalidateSession` action in the component itself and do `this.sendAction('invalidateSession')` in its implementation so that the action is forwarded to the controller/route the component os rendered in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Simple Auth `ApplicationRouteMixin` to your `ApplicationRoute`.  For example if you are using ES6 modules do

```
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend ApplicationRouteMixin,
```

The action should bubble up to the application route, where it will be handled.

See the documentation [here](http://ember-simple-auth.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-ApplicationRouteMixin)

Comment: I'm using ember-cli, and that code is already in "routes/application.js". Doesn't work.

Comment: Is the action actually bubbling up to `ApplicationRoute`?  If you're triggering it inside a component you will need to explicitly bubble it up with `this.sendAction`.   I believe controllers and routes will do this automatically but components will not.

Comment: Documented [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/).  You would do something like `my-component logoutAction='invalidateSession'` and inside it `sendAction('logoutAction', <optional params>)`.  I think if you just define `action='something'` then `this.sendAction()` will default to that.  If you have multiple levels of components currently you need to pass it up through each one.

Comment: This seems to work, although after the signout the page is reloaded twice :/